# Batch nested code incorrect?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, nested

```
if %CHO%==1 (
    set cost=35
    if %GP% GEQ %cost% (
        echo Do want to replace %WEP% with Broadsword?
        set /p CHO=
        if %CHO%==yes (
            set /a GP=%GP%-35
            set WEP=Broadsword
            goto weapon
        )
        if %CHO%==Yes (
            set /a GP=%GP%-35
            set WEP=Broadsword
            goto weapon
        )
        if %CHO%==no goto weapon
        if %CHO%==No goto weapon
    )
    if %GP% LSS %cost% (
        echo You don't have enough GP!
        pause
        goto weapon
    )
)
```

Whenever I run this code, cmd says that the syntax of the command is incorrect and closes. I thought nesting within nesting was allowed in batch. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you writing a game in a .cmd file? Have you considered other languages for this? In any case, you need to provide more info... where does it fail?

Comment: I am actually using multiple cmd files that call each other up and edit each other to "save" your progress. I decided to make a game from scratch, using no programs.

Comment: It is written in a .bat file. It goes wrong as soon as I enter the 1 and this code is run.

Comment: batch interpreter is a program thats not coded by you. Anyway make sure that the variables do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire IF construct is parsed as one block and all variables are evaluated only once, at the start.

You can rearrange your code without loops and variables in them, or you will have to use SETLOCAL ENABLEDDELAYEDEXPANSION and use `!cost!` instead of `%cost%` (for example) for any variables that are set within your loop construct.

Answer (score 0):

This should be functionally the same as your code.
It uses delayed expansion on variables that are created within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%CHO%"=="1" (
    set cost=35
    if %GP% GEQ !%cost! (
        echo Do want to replace %WEP% with Broadsword?
        set /p CHO=
        if /i "!CHO!"=="yes" (
            set /a GP=%GP%-35
            set WEP=Broadsword
          ) else (
            echo You don't have enough GP!
            pause
          )
    )
 goto weapon
)
```

Note the `/i` in the if compare which makes the compare case insensitive.
Also the quotes surrounding the compare terms will prevent a simple enter keypress from breaking your code.  It allows the use of two word terms to be used too.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix it. I actually found that the setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion wasn't necessary and the code ran fine with just the exclamation points around the variables set in the nested code.

Comment: It must have had delayed expansion already enabled.  Glad you got it fixed.